# Find multivariable limit.

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I need a hint on what kind of path I should choose to show that this limit does not exist:

$\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,2)}\frac{(xy - 2x)}{x^3 + (y - 2)^2}$

Comment: Did you try $(0,y)$ and $(x, x^2+2)$?

Comment: You can simplify things a bit by noting your expression is the same as $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}{xy\over x^3+y^2}$.

Comment: I would of never had thought of putting x^2 + 2 into y. What was your thought process? Are there some patterns or techniques?

Comment: Try to evaluate the limit along the path
$$y = 2+x^{3/2}$$ and then evaluate the limit first letting $x \to 0$ and then $y \to 2$.

Comment: what about straight lines?$ y-2=kx$? the limit on these should be $1/k$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have 
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,2)}\frac{(xy - 2x)}{x^3 + (y - 2)^2}
&
=
\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,2)}\frac{x(y - 2)}{x^3 + (y - 2)^2}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

If $f(x,y)=\frac{xy)}{x^3 + y^2}$ and $\varphi(x,y)=(x,y-2)$ then 
$$
\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,+2)}\varphi(x,y)=(0,0)
$$
and 
$$
\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(\varphi(x,y))= \displaystyle\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,2)}\frac{x(y - 2)}{x^3 + (y - 2)^2}
$$
But 
$\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)$ don't exist, by cause if $x=y=t$ we have 
$$
\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{xy}{x^3 + y^2}
=
\displaystyle\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{t^2}{t^3 + t^2}
=
\displaystyle\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{1}{t + 1}=1
$$
and if $x=t$, $y=2t$ we have 
$$
\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{xy}{x^3 + y^2}
=
\displaystyle\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{2t^2}{t^3 + 4t^2}
=
\displaystyle\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{2}{t + 4}=\frac{1}{2}
$$

Comment: @DavidMitra I update my Answer.